# Checking to see if array is full

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an Array `Candy[] type;`

and `type = new Candy[capacity];`

if the Array is full is `capacity = type.length` ?

Comment: Add language into tags

Comment: What language do u need it? C++ or Java or?

Comment: There's no such thing as "full" for an array. It just has a constant number of elements (after creation). I suggest you use an `ArrayList<Candy>` instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using array, the size of array is determined during compilation. Thus if your intention is to check whether current array's index has reached the last array element, you may use the following condtion (possibly in a loop) to check whether your current array index is the last element. If it is true, then it has reached the last element of your array.

**Example:**

```java
     int[] candy = new int[10];  //Array size is 10
     //first array: Index 0, last array index: 9. 
     for (int x=0; x < candy.length; x++)
           if (x == candy.length - 1)
                //Reached last element of array
```

You can check the **size** of the array by using:

```
candy.length
```

You check whether it is **last element** by using:

```
if (currentIndex == candy.length - 1) //Where candy is your array
```

Make sure you are using **double equal** `==` for comparison.

Single equal `=` is for assignment.

Answer (score 4):

Java creates an array with `capacity` count of references to the `Candy` instances initializing array with the `null`s. So any array in java is full and

```
type.length == capacity
```

is always true.

`type = new Candy[capacity]` is equivalent to

```
type = new Candy[] {null, null, null, /* capacity count of nulls */, null};
```

Comment: So it is wrong if I do the 1 equal sign right? I have to use two equal signs because I am return a Boolean correct?

Answer (score 2):

In the example you show `type.length` will always be equal to `capacity`(after the initialization). Also your array will always have `capacity` elements but they will initially all be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if array is full (no null elements), use something like this:

```
//1
boolean b = false;

//2
for(int i = 0; i < type.length; i++){
    if(type[i] == null){
        b = true;
    }
}

//3
if(b == false){
    System.out.println("Array is full");
}
```

What does it mean?

//1. At beginning you have one boolean  (b) which is false.

//2. If any value in your array is null, b will be true.

//3. You check if value of b is still false. If it is, that means that b is never changed, so array is full (no null elements) .

Comment: If your last array value is different of null b = true. Even if all your previous data are still nul.

Comment: Question is to check if array is full or not.. If any value is null "b" will be true. If b is true, that means that at least one element is null and array is not full.