# How to check if an array is full in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a project where I have to run a certain function once an array has reached 6 elements. I am working with an array of nested arrays and I must check to see if each array has reached 6 elements in capacity. How would I go about doing this? Here is my JS

```
board.every(cell => {
    //checking every array to see if it has 6 elements
    if(cell.length === 7) {
    alert('full!')
      endGame()
    }
})
```

`board` is the parent array and `cell` represents each nested array. `cell.length` is not solving the issue.

Comment: What does "full" mean in this context? A certain length?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between `cell.length - 1 === 7` and wanting six elements, but. You're not providing enough information. Is the array built up, e.g., via `push`, or is the array already there and it's the *content* of the array elements that determines if it's "filled"?

Comment: Do you simply want something like this? `const isFull = (board) => board .every (cell => cell .length >= 6)`?

Comment: Arrays in javascript dynamically resize, so what does full mean? If "full" means 6 entries then your current code works.

Comment: This can be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942115/checking-to-see-if-array-is-full

Comment: Also, why are you subtracting from `cell.length`?  [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) will always just give you the length of the array, you don't have to worry about it being zero-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the following solution:

```
const isFull = board.every(cell => cell.length === 6)

if (isFull) {
   endGame();
   alert('full');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` instead of `every`:

```js
const cell1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const cell2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const board = [cell1, cell2]
const endgame = () => {console.log('full!')}
        
board.forEach(cell => {
    //checking every array to see if it has 6 elements
    if(cell.length === 6) {
        endgame()
    }    
})
```