# Java Connect4 game . I want to check if the column is full

Tags: java

I am trying to check if the column that the player wants to put a coin is full . When i put the column is full and i put another coin there it goes out of bounds.How can i check if it is full and not going out of bonds.

```java
for(int o = rows- 1;o>= 0; o--) {
    if (boards[o][nextColumn]=="- " ) {
        boards[o][nextColumn] = nextSymbol + " " ;
        break;
    }
    if (fullColumn > rows ) {
        System.out.println("The column is full!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ... so post your complete code

Comment: As an immediate guess as to why this is failing however, you're using `boards[o][nextColumn]=="- "` which is a `String` identity comparison.  `"- ".equals(boards[o][nextColumn])` is what you want there (`==` checks if they are the same _instance_ of a `String`, which they likely aren't).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking to see if array is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942115/checking-to-see-if-array-is-full)

Comment: i changed it . The same problem stays. My code is like 350 rows. and it says : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 6
 at Main.main(Main.java:344)
where int line 344 line i have the diagonial check if there is a winner 

for(int g=0;g<rows;g++) {
       for (int s=0; s<columns;s++) {
        if(!(boards[g][s].equals("- ") ) && boards[g][s].equals(boards[g-1][s+1]) && boards[g][s].equals(boards[g-2][s+2]) && boards[g][s].equals(boards[g-3][s+3]) )

Comment: e.g. you loop g starting from 0... now in boards[g-1][s+1]) you get the error when g is 0 because you try to access the element at boars[ -1][s+1]... and -1 is no valid index

Comment: @JavaMan Thanks a lot ! . One more .. when the user sets for example rows==6 and columns == 7 , when he wants to put the coin on 7 the first coin goes and then in the same line as befor it says .....Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 7

Comment: you can't access index 7 for an array with length 7 because the index of the elements are starting with 0 and go up to 6, not 7 .... just add some output of the values you will access ..then you should easily find out what part causes the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting IndexOutOfBoundsException because when you initialize your loop, the value of `g` is 0.

```
for(int g=0;g<rows;g++)
```

Then while you're on the same iteration of the loop, you're checking to see if the next cell contains the same symbol as the current cell, but you're doing it by decrementing `g`.

```
boards[g][s].equals(boards[g-1][s+1])
```

If the value of `g` starts at zero, then the value of `g-1` is -1, which produces the error because your array starts at index 0 by definition.

When you are checking your diagonals, you can't do it just one way -- diagonals are directional. Not accounting for that directionality is what makes your test fail.

Get a piece of paper and draw your board

```
Diagonal 1

3 - - - o
2 - - o -
1 - o - -
0 o - - -
  0 1 2 3

Diagonal 2

3 o - - -
2 - o - -
1 - - o -
0 - - - o
  0 1 2 3
```

In the case of diagonal 1, you need to increment both `g` and `s` together, but since we know that `g == s` for every point on the first diagonal, we only need one variable.

```
for(int g = 0; g < 4;g++)
{
    if(boards[g][g].equals(boards[g + 1][g + 1]))
    {
        // still matching. I have no idea how your code is tracking
        // matches, so you'll have to adapt this on your own
    }
    else
    {
        // no match, no need to continue the loop
        // break; or exit however you want
    }
}
```

For diagonal 2, just as we know `g == s` for all points of diagonal 1, we know that `g == 3 - s`, so you can do

```
for(int s = 0; s < 4;s++)
{
    if(boards[(3 - s)][s].equals(boards[2 - s][s + 1]))
    {
        // still matching. I have no idea how your code is tracking
        // matches, so you'll have to adapt this on your own
    }
    else
    {
        // no match, no need to continue the loop
        // break; or exit however you want
    }
}
```

Whenever you can't wrap your head around something, draw a picture and work it on paper until you understand what you're dealing with.